# All permutations with repetition using scala

Tags: scala, combinations, combinatorics, repeat

I am looking for the scala way to give all permutations without repetitions. I know there are some postings on this site already but they seem to have a slightly different problem.

I am searching for all permutations with repetitions.
For example:

```
combine(List('A','C','G'))
```

Should yield:

```
List(List('A'.'A','A'),List('A'.'A','C'),List('A'.'A','G'),List('A'.'C','A'),
List('A'.'C',''C), ... List('G'.'G','G')
```

I am sorry if my problem is already solved but I was not able to find it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My own approach (doesn't compile):

```
def combine(size: Int = sym.length) : List[List[T]] = {
  size match {
    case 0 => List()
    case 1 => sym.toList.map(List(_))
    case _ => for (el <- sym) yield el :: combine(size-1)
  }
}
```

sym is an array member of a class which contains all the symbols to be combined.

Comment: This describes the list of _all permutations_ of all combinations of the input list

Comment: Nope, it describes all *permutations with repetitions*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def combinations(size: Int = sym.length) : List[List[T]] = {
    if (size == 0)
        List(List())
    else {
        for {
            x  <- sym.toList
            xs <- combinations(size-1)
        } yield x :: xs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

With Scalaz:

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> def combine[A](xs: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
     |   xs.replicate[List](xs.size).sequence
     | }
combine: [A](xs: List[A])List[List[A]]

scala> combine(List('A', 'C', 'G'))
res47: List[List[Char]] = List(List(A, A, A), List(A, A, C), List(A, A, G), List
(A, C, A), List(A, C, C), List(A, C, G), List(A, G, A), List(A, G, C), List(A, G
, G), List(C, A, A), List(C, A, C), List(C, A, G), List(C, C, A), List(C, C, C),
 List(C, C, G), List(C, G, A), List(C, G, C), List(C, G, G), List(G, A, A), List
(G, A, C), List(G, A, G), List(G, C, A), List(G, C, C), List(G, C, G), List(G, G
, A), List(G, G, C), List(G, G, G))
```

Comment: This is much cuter in Haskell: `combine = sequence . (replicate =<< length)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore with the latest version of Scalaz.  It seems there's only a `replicateM(n: Int)` method in the library, but no `replicate[List](n: Int)` method.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo, this answer was written more than six years ago. Nothing in Scalaz is the same any more.

Comment: yes, I see that... still worth pointing out, don't you think?  ...so people don't waste time trying this solution as is?  Perhaps you would consider updating your solution so that it's still helpful.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo, alas, I no longer have that kind of time these days. :) But please feel free to update it per the new version!

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
val input = List('A','C','G')

(input ++ input ++ input) combinations(3) toList
```

Comment: +1 Or when you don't know the size of the original list: ```(input.map(_ => input)).flatten.combinations(3).toList```

Comment: @opyate Nice :). It could be even shortened to `input.flatMap(_ => input).combinations(3).toList`. My closest different not-so-nice approach is `Seq.fill(input.size)(input).flatten.combinations(3).toList`.

Comment: This does not match the OP's specification.  For example, your result will include `List('A', 'A', 'C')`, as it should, but it will not include `List('A', 'C', 'A')`, nor `List('C', 'A', 'A')`.  The OP wants all three-element lists, where the ordering of elements in each list matters.

Comment: Put another way, the OP is asking for permutations, not just combinations.

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> def comb(s:String)=(s * s.length).combinations(s.length)
comb: (s: String)Iterator[String]

scala> comb("ACG").toList
res16: List[String] = List(AAA, AAC, AAG, ACC, ACG, AGG, CCC, CCG, CGG, GGG)
```

And if you wanted the resulting permutations:

```
scala> comb("ACG").flatMap(_.toSeq.permutations.toList).toList
res11: List[Seq[Char]] = List(AAA, AAC, ACA, CAA, AAG, AGA, GAA, ACC, CAC, CCA, ACG, AGC, CAG, CGA, GAC, GCA, AGG, GAG, GGA, CCC, CCG, CGC, GCC, CGG, GCG, GGC, GGG)
```

You can leave out the `toList` but it's there so you can see the results.

Comment: ACA is the same *combination* as AAC.  Its a different *permutation*

Comment: Ah, yes. I was just reading the OP's examples, which included both AAC and ACA, rather than what he actually asked for. My bad.

Comment: Yes, well spotted, the OP probably wanted permutations.  I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems no one has suggested the easiest---or, at least, easiest to read---solution.  It is

```
myList = List("A", "C", "G")
for {
  i <- myList
  j <- myList
  k <- myList
} yield List(i,j,k)
```

(This is syntactic sugar for the following composition of maps:

```
myList.flatMap(i => myList.flatMap(j => myList.map(k => List(i,j,k))))
```

to which the Scala compiler translates the above `for` expression.)

Answer (score 0):

In ScalaZ 7

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
def combinine[T](l: List[T]) = l.replicateM(l.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just making a more generic answers, from @opyate and @monnef:

```scala
// considering that we want a permutation_size
List.fill(permutation_size)(input).flatten.combinations(permutation_size).toList
```

This will generate the permutation with repetition with size permutation_size:

```scala
val a = List.fill(2)(List("A","B","C")).flatten.combinations(2).toList
a: List[List[String]] = List(List(A, A), List(A, B), List(A, C), List(B, B), List(B, C), List(C, C))
```

and

```scala
val a = List.fill(3)(List("A","B","C")).flatten.combinations(3).toList
a: List[List[String]] = List(List(A, A, A), List(A, A, B), List(A, A, C), List(A, B, B), List(A, B, C), List(A, C, C), List(B, B, B), List(B, B, C), List(B, C, C), List(C, C, C))
```

Comment: This is not a solution.  Your result doesn't match the OP's specification.  Notice you won't have the entry `List(A, C, A)`, but the OP wants that included in the result.